# JS prototype inheritance for custom classes

Tags: javascript

There is two constructor functions: Animal and Rabbit (classes emulation). How can I set inheritance for this classes using prototypes properly? I seen 2 versions:

```
Rabbit.prototype.__proto__ = Animal.prototype;
```

I think it works good as I expected. But this version doesn't work in IE10-, and there is the following version:

```
Rabbit.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
```

This version looks good too, but I must create an additional object for it. Which version is preferred? May be there is anything else? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The version `Rabbit.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);` is prefered.

Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) gives the following warning about `__proto__`:

> Warning: Changing the [[Prototype]] of an object is, by the nature of how modern JavaScript engines optimize property accesses, a very slow operation, in every browser and JavaScript engine. The effects on performance of altering inheritance are subtle and far-flung, and are not limited to simply the time spent in obj.**proto** = ... statement, but may extend to any code that has access to any object whose [[Prototype]] has been altered. If you care about performance you should avoid setting the [[Prototype]] of an object. Instead, create a new object with the desired [[Prototype]] using Object.create().

Answer (score 0):

You should have something like this:

```
Rabbit.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Rabbit.prototype.constructor = Rabbit;
```

If you won't write second line instance of `Rabbit` will have `Animal` constructor.

Also it's possible to do:

```
Rabbit.prototype = new Animal();
```

but in this case you will also trigger constructor, which is not preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Every object has an internal [[Prototype]] property whose value is the object from which the former inherits from.

Then `Rabbit.prototype.__proto__ = Animal.prototype` changes the [[Prototype]] of `Rabbit.prototype` so that it inherits from `Animal.prototype`.

Instead, `Rabbit.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype)` replaces the entire `Rabbit.prototype` with a different object, which inherits from `Animal.prototype`.

In practice, the differences are:

- Modifying the [[Prototype]] is considered a bad practice by lots of people, and has bad performance.
- Replacing the entire prototype with a different object will only affect instances created after that. Previous instances will still inherit from the previous `Rabbit.prototype`.
- If you replace the entire prototype with a different object, you should consider copying the own properties (and symbols) of the old one. For example, the `constructor` property.